# How to simplify this equality between ArcCos and ArcCsc?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I'm trying to make Mathematica confirm that the following is true:

```
FullSimplify[ArcCos[Sqrt[1/2 (2 + M)/(1 + M)]] == ArcCsc[Sqrt[2 + 2/M]], M > 0]
```

But it stubbornly returns me unchanged equality. How to make Mathematica evaluate it to `True` (since it *is* true)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a change of variables `M == 1/m`

```
M > 0 /. M -> 1/m // Simplify

(*  m > 0  *)

eqn = ArcCos[Sqrt[1/2 (2 + M)/(1 + M)]] == ArcCsc[Sqrt[2 + 2/M]];

eqn /. M -> 1/m // TrigToExp //
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
 FullSimplify[#, m > 0] &

(*  True  *)
```

Or equivalently,

```
expr = ArcCos[Sqrt[1/2 (2 + M)/(1 + M)]] - ArcCsc[Sqrt[2 + 2/M]];

expr /. M -> 1/m // TrigToExp //
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
 FullSimplify[#, m > 0] &

(*  0  *)
```

Comment: Funnily, neither `Re` nor `Im` appear in the output of `ComplexExpand`, although the whole thing ultimately does evaluate to `True`. Also, how did you guess to do this exact change of variables?

Comment: @Ruslan - I was looking for a simpler form and `eqn /. M -> 1/m // Simplify` looked simpler and the arguments of the trig functions had more commonality.

Answer (score 5):

If you are fine with reformulating the equation as

```
eq = ArcCos[Sqrt[1/2 (2 + M)/(1 + M)]] - ArcCsc[Sqrt[2 + 2/M]] == 0
```

then one option is the slightly clunky

```
FullSimplify[TrigToExp[eq] /. a_ Log[b_] + a_ Log[c_] :> a Log[b c], M > 0]
```

> > True

Looking at the output of `TrigToExp[eq]` should explain the need for the `Log` replacement rule.